# Let $X$ and $Y$ be jointly continuous random variables. Find an expression for the density of $Z=X-Y$

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables, density-function

This question was from the problem section of my textbook but I'm not sure how to start it.

At first, I thought it would just be like finding the sum of two variables which can be found in the textbook: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HUZc.jpg

How do you deal with the random variables if they aren't independent? Should I just follow the example for the sum of two random variables but just stop right before the part where it assumes they are independent?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if they aren't independent, you can't go any further. Of course you will also have to modify the set $R_z$ from the textbook because they were dealing with $X+Y$ and you are looking at $X-Y$.